# Disable client side validation for radio button control MVC C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I have 2 series of radio buttons on a screen. By default the second set are hidden.

When I click the Yes radio button of the first set I tell it to show the second set. this works fine.

If I select the No radio button of the first set it will not work if that is the first radio button I click.

For example if I select Yes, I see the second set, if I then select No the second set goes away and I can move to the next screen. If I select the No first I am not able to move to the next screen. See code:

```js
//this hides a div tag that contains all the controls to be hidden
$("#Hide12D2").hide();

$("input[name='TwelveD1']").on("change",
  function() {
    if ($(this).val() === "true") {
      //this is triggered if the first radio button is selected.
      $("#Hide12D2").show();
    } else if ($(this).val() === "false") {
      //this is triggered when the second one is select but does not work the first time
      $("#TwelveD2").remove();
      $("#Hide12D2").hide();

    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please add the rendered HTML to the Stack Snippet I added to your question to that we can see what's going wrong with your JavaScript.

Comment: that the thing. When i run the app I can't see anything when looking for the page in source and it just renders a radio button but I also cant see the JavaScript on the page that i posted above. really odd

Comment: Right-click the radio button and select Inspect Element (or similar). You should get to a tab that shows the rendered DOM. Right click a suitable parent element and select Copy as HTML or Copy > Outer HTML (varies by browser).

Comment: I was able to use  $("#controlname").rules("remove","required"); to get it to work